# GPS accuracy Issues

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows phone sports tracker app, that uses gps sensors to calculate the distance travelled by the runner, I am using geocoordinatewatcher class for the same, setting the movement threshold to 100. But, I find my app giving distance values even when the device is kept stationary. My app should give distance only when the device changes its position. I found the same bug in othere apps that are on the marketplace, please tell me where am I doing wrong?
My Code.

```
  watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
                    watcher.MovementThreshold = 150;
                    watcher.PositionChanged += watcher_PositionChanged;
                    watcher.Start();
 {
            latitudeCurrent = e.Position.Location.Latitude;
            longitudeCurrent = e.Position.Location.Longitude;
            if (stepCounter == 0)
            {
                latitudePrevious = latitudeCurrent;
                longitudePrevious = longitudeCurrent;
                distanceTravelled += Math.Round(Calculate(latitudePrevious,longitudePrevious,latitudeCurrent,longitudeCurrent),2);
                txbDistanceTravelled.Text = distanceTravelled.ToString();
                txbCalories.Text=string.Format("{0:f0}", distanceTravelled * 65);
                stepCounter++;
                var millisPerKilometer = (distanceTravelled) * (System.Environment.TickCount - _previousPositionChangeTick);
                txbPace.Text = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisPerKilometer).ToString(@"mm\:ss");
                double hrs = counterTick / 3600;
                if (!double.IsNaN((distanceTravelled / hrs)))
                {
                    txbSpeed.Text = (distanceTravelled / hrs).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    txbSpeed.Text = "0";
                }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you testing the device outside or indoors on WiFi? If you are indoors it is likely you are not using GPS so are loosing a level of accuracy, and switching to cell or wifi positions. Maybe enabled some logged debug information and take you device for a walk outside and see what results you get.

Answer (score 0):

You are developing your app for Windows Phone 7 or Windows Phone 8? IF you are developing for the later, you need to use the new Geolocator class and not GeoCoordinateWatcher.

Also, as LewisBenge said, if you are testing This indoor you can get WiFi positions or even cellular data. It could be better to test outdoor.

Answer (score 0):

Your GPS signal might be weak in the place where you are testing. Try it in the outdoor location.